# Want to bring data from Oracle warehouse to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, case

I want to bring data from Oracle Datawarehouse to SQL Server based on condition.

I have 3 segment columns(seg_1,seg_2,seg_3) in table_A in Datawarehouse, want bring them into SQL but I want make them as one column based on column present in SQL server table_B. I will run stored procedure to do it.

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE WHEN seg_1 in (select seg from [Servername].[dbname].[schemaname].[table_B]) then seg_1
            WHEN seg_2 in (select seg from [Servername].[dbname].[schemaname].[table_B]) then seg_2
            WHEN seg_3 in (select seg from [Servername].[dbname].[schemaname].[table_B]) then seg_3
       End
from table_A
```

When I'm trying run above code in Stored Procedure it is giving error as table_B is invalid table name. The table is present in that server and database. Please help me to do it.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  You need for `table_B` to exist.  You might want to investigate why you think it should exist and it doesn't.

Comment: In addition to Gordon's comment, your code does not explicitly specify a schema name for either `table_A` or `table_B`, in which case your query may not "see" the tables even if they exist, because they may not be in your user's default schema, or dbo. Specify the schema names for the tables in the query.

Comment: Hi I have specified table names as follows
[Serveename].[dbname].[schemaname].[tableame] but still got error as invalid table name.

Comment: Where does Oracle come into this? Is `[Servername].[dbname].[schemaname].[table_B]` meant to refer to an Oracle table? Please clarify, it's not clear in your question.

Comment: If this meant to refer to Oracle, the format should be `SELECT * FROM LinkedServer..Schema.Table`